# What is the best way to display data from database android ?

Tags: android, controls

I used ListView to display data from database , for example I have three columns and I use new line for each column in the same ListView item ,but I wondered if there is control like data table for android, what do you think the best control to use in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

ListView with a CursorLoader might be you're best option:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html
My team built a table as just a ListView with consistent widget widths across rows.

Could checkout other subclasses of AdapterView, which support the same kind of data loading.
Here is a guide:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/binding.html
And the reference:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html

Curious if anyone knows something better, maybe a good 3rd party option?

Comment: can you explain "My team built a table as just a ListView with consistent widget widths across rows." if you have photo !

Comment: @MohammedSubhiSheikhQuroush : ListView only has rows (not columns), but rows are linear layouts, so we add multiple widgets to each row, one for each column, and they are fixed width so that they align across rows.  

Found a nice example including screenshots and codes here:  

http://www.technotalkative.com/android-multi-column-listview/